# C# Multiview Persist Data

Tags: c#, multiview

I am currently using a multiview control within a web forms user control page, navigating between views, our data does not persist.

Three view, last view contains a summary of what was entered within the first two view, If I click through to the summary view on ly data from the seconds view is available.

Clicking back and forth between views, our form data is lost.

Any ideas where to begin?

**.ascx** Page

```
    <asp:MultiView ID="MultiView1" ActiveViewIndex="0" EnableViewState="true" runat="server">
    <asp:View ID="View1" runat="server">
        Name:<br />
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtName" runat="server" />
    </asp:View>
    <asp:View ID="View2" runat="server">
        Surname:<br />
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtSurname" runat="server" />
    </asp:View>
    <asp:View ID="View3" runat="server">
        <b>Summary</b><br />
        Name:
        <asp:Label ID="lblName" runat="server" /><br />
        Surname:
        <asp:Label ID="lblSurname" runat="server" /><br />
    </asp:View>
</asp:MultiView>
<asp:Button ID="btnBack" runat="server" Text="&lt; Back " OnClick="btnBack_Click" />
<asp:Button ID="btnNext" runat="server" Text="Next &gt;" OnClick="btnNext_Click" />
<asp:Button ID="btnSend" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClick="btnSend_Click" />
```

**ascx.cs** Codebehind

```
    protected void btnBack_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MultiView1.ActiveViewIndex--;
    }
    protected void btnNext_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MultiView1.ActiveViewIndex++;
    }
    protected void btnSend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }
    protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
    {
        if (MultiView1.ActiveViewIndex == MultiView1.Views.Count - 1)
        {
            FillSummary();
        }
        btnBack.Visible = MultiView1.ActiveViewIndex > 0;
        btnNext.Visible = MultiView1.ActiveViewIndex < MultiView1.Views.Count - 1;
        btnSend.Visible = MultiView1.ActiveViewIndex == MultiView1.Views.Count - 1;
        base.OnPreRender(e);
    }
    private void FillSummary()
    {
        lblName.Text = txtName.Text;
        lblSurname.Text = txtSurname.Text;
    }
```

Comment: (1) Are you sure that ViewState is enabled in all parent elements of the multiview? (2) Does the behavior change if you debug (set a breakpoint in `OnPreRender` and check the values for `lblName.Text` `txtName.Text` `lblSurname.Text` and `txtSurname.Text`

Comment: Hi @peter `EnableViewState="true"` is enable on the `multiview` control, therefore all child textboxes should inherit the viewstate.


I have set a breakpoint in `OnPreRender`, `lblName.Text` remains null however `lblSurname.Text` equals whatever string is typed into the Surname textbox

Comment: What are the values for mentioned variables after the first btnNext_Click, when your second input form is loading?

Comment: @grek40 it is empty/null.

in the first textbox, I insert "_John_", click next, enter "_Doe_" in the surname textbox, click next to get to the summary and only the surname value is read.

For some reason the values do not persist, while on the summary page, clicking the back button the surname textbox value of "_Doe_" is removed.

Comment: Please read my question carefully. *I insert "John", click next* - NOW you should look with the debugger, not after the second 'next' click.

Comment: @grek40 after the first click, txtName is empty/null.

Comment: Do you have any `Page_Init` or `Page_Load` code? When the value is not included in the first Postback, then the problem should be independent from the viewstate.

Comment: @grek40 they are not present in my `ascx.cs` what i have written above is all I have. thanks for your patience, this has been racking my brain

Comment: Is the ascx control a static part of an aspx file or is it dynamically loaded somewhere in code behind? Maybe you can edit some of the utilization side logic into the question.

Comment: I am currently testing both as static and dynamically loaded, the same issue happens.

Comment: I don't know how to approach the problem further withouut an actual project, so if you can provide a [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), I'll have a look at it. Otherwise you have to figure out yourself or wait for someone else ;)

Comment: thanks for your assistance, I will revert to using jQuery to toggle visibility.